# correct import path for setuptools

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools

I'm installing a project with `setuptools` but couldn't get the import path correct.

The project is simple:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── europe
    │   ├── germany.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── hello.py
    └── __init__.py
```

```py
# setup.py:
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name="hello_world",
    version="1.0.0",
    description='testing setuptools',
    packages=find_packages(where="."),
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires='>=3.0',
    install_requires=[],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["hello_world = src.hello:main"]
    },
)
```

```py
# src/__init__.py
from . import europe
```

```py
# src/hello.py
from src.europe.germany import hello_germany


def main():
    hello_germany()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`src/europe/__init__.py` contains nothing

```py
# src/europe/germany.py
def hello_germany():
    print("gutten Tag")
```

With current code I can pack it and install (you need `setuptools` and `wheel` for this step, both can be installed from conda or pip), then I got an executable binary `hello_world`:

```
$ python3 setup.py install
$ hello_world
gutten Tag
```

It works fine without any problem.

But I just couldn't invoke it as python script any more:

```
$ pip uninstall hello-world
$ python3 src/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blahblah/src/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.europe.germany import hello_germany
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

It complains on the import statement `from src.europe.germany import hello_germany` that `src` can't be found.

I can of course change `from src.europe.germany import hello_germany` to `from europe.germany import hello_germany` but then the packaing and installation don't work any more:

```
$ python3 setup.py install 
$ hello_world
  File "blahblah/anaconda3/envs/py312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/hello_world-1.0.0-py3.12.egg/src/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from europe.germany import hello_germany
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'europe'
```

It complains module `europe` can't be found.

How do I fix the import path to get it working both as a script and as a pip wheel package?